# How to move the data from the supertype to the subtype in Hybris?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I added a new attribute to my custom model (**CustomApparelProduct**), which extends from **ApparelProduct** model. **ApparelProduct** already extends **ProductModel** (SAP core model).

extension-items.xml

```
<typegroup name="Apparel">
            <itemtype code="ApparelProduct" extends="Product"
                      autocreate="true" generate="true"
                      jaloclass="de.hybris.training.core.jalo.ApparelProduct">
                <description>Base apparel product extension that contains additional attributes.</description>
                <attributes>
                    <attribute qualifier="genders" type="GenderList">
                        <description>List of genders that the ApparelProduct is designed for</description>
                        <modifiers/>
                        <persistence type="property"/>
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
            </itemtype>

            <itemtype code="CustomApparelProduct" extends="ApparelProduct"
                      autocreate="true" generate="true" > // My custom type
                <description> Custom Apparel Product that contains total amount attributes</description>
                <attributes>
                    <attribute qualifier="amount" type="java.lang.Integer">
                        <description>Total buying amount </description>
                        <modifiers/>
                        <persistence type="property"/>
                        <defaultvalue>Integer.valueOf(0)</defaultvalue>
                    </attribute>
                </attributes>
            </itemtype>
```

When I go to Hybris Admin Console to check the data from my new Types by using FlexibleSearch, the result is that all the fields lack data. ( The picture below is from my **CustomApparelProduct** type)

[image]

When I check the FlexibleSearch for **ApparelProduct** type and **Product** type, the result is that all the fields hava data. ( The picture below is from **ApparelProduct** type)

[image]

I don't know what I need to transfer the original data from **Product** to my new type **CustomApparelProduct**. The original data was inserted to system using impex and csv file; the type used to insert is **Product**.

How I can transfer thedata to my custom type?

Comment: Do you still have the impex that was used to insert data? 
I would edit the impex to remove the all, then I would insert them all again into the new type.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change from Type A to Type B easily/directly.

You need to migrate the data. i.e. Delete Type A item. Re-insert/create item as Type B. Also, check if there are other dependencies that need to be updated.